# Get foreign key without requesting the whole object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model Foo which have a ForeignKey to the User model.

Later, I need to grab all the User's id and put then on a list

```
foos = Foo.objects.filter(...)

l = [ f.user.id for f in foos ]
```

But when I do that, django grabs the whole User instance from the DB instead of giving me just the numeric user's id, which exist in each Foo row.

How can I get all the ids without querying each user or using a select_related?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [queryset's values() function](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields), which will return a list of dictionaries containing name/value pairs for each attribute passed as parameters:

```
>>> Foo.objects.all().values('user__id')
[{'user__id': 1}, {'user__id' 2}, {'user__id': 3}]
```

The ORM will then be able to optimize the SQL query to only return the required fields, instead of doing a "SELECT *".

Comment: Hi Daniel,

Your answer will help me in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Will accessing  user__id perform a JOIN? since it has to access the "id" attribute of the User table?

Comment: No - this is what I get out of django.db.connection.queries: SELECT "app_foo"."user_id" FROM "app_foo".  the "__id" is superfluous, since the foreign key is only the ID to begin with.  but specifying it seems more idiomatic to me, to make clear that you're getting an integer and not a user object.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you define a ForeignKey in Django, it automatically adds a FIELD_id field to your model.

For instance, if `Foo` has a FK to `User` with an attribute named "`user`", then you also have an attribute named **user_id** which contains the id of the related user.

```
l = [ f.user_id for f in foos ]
```

Calling `.values()` also adds performance if you select your attributes wisely

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I´m not sure why this didn´t work before when I tried, but this is how to do:

```
l = [ f.user_id for f in foos ]
```